# How to pass a url in a dictionary to the function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to call a function by passing a url to it but I can't quite figure how it can be done for my use case.

On the last line in the code below, there is what I would like to do. I know it's terrible to enter dictionary key in a function like that, but I don't know how to properly pass the `def` key of the `urls` dictionary to the `get_page()` function. Thanks for your guidance.

This is my code:

```
...
urls = {
    "abc": abc_url,
    "def": def_url,
}

if site in urls:
    print("site: " + site, "url: " + urls[site])

    products = get_index_data(get_page(urls[site]))

    for link in products:
        time.sleep(15)
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))

        print(data)
        write_csv(data, link)


def get_page(urls[site]):

    ...code continues...
```

Comment: just use `def get_page(url_var)`. when you call `get_page(urls[site])` your `get_page` function will automatically copy the url value to `url_var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

As python is an interpreted language (which reads code line by line and does not compile); hence function implementation should be before the function call.

Now coming to your question, when calling `get_page(urls[site]))` it passes the value from dictionary. 
So your function should have a parameter like `def get_page(website_url):`

To summarise -

```
...

urls = {
    "abc": abc_url,
    "def": def_url,
}

def get_page(website_url):
    ...function code...

if site in urls:
    print("site: " + site, "url: " + urls[site])

    products = get_index_data(get_page(urls[site]))

    for link in products:
        time.sleep(15)
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))

        print(data)
        write_csv(data, link)

...code continues...
```

**Note**: You can get both keys, values from a dictionary like

```
if website_name, website_url in urls.items():
```